# How to disable javascript using the web console?

Tags: firefox, javascript

I start using the Web Console that is built-in to Firefox 18.

Do you know any command I can use to disable JavaScript directly from the web console?

PS: Before I was using the addon webdeveloper toolbar where you find such an option, but I would like to be able to switch off JavaScript quickly without addon (and without changing Firefox's settings each time).

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to disable javascript using the Web Console:

```
pref set javascript.enabled false
```

And enable it again:

```
pref set javascript.enabled true
```

Comment: Another option for Firefox 25: When opening the web console and clicking the settings icon on the very left there will be a checkbox to "Disable Javascript" (only for the session).

Comment: That does not work in Firefox 102.6.0esr (syntax not accepted)